# HTML not working when opened from file, works from ftp server

Tags: html, css, ftp

I am trying to write html and css for a web page, but it doesn't show anything when I open the file directly from the file. It works fine when I access it through my ftp server, even from the same pc and browser. I have tried searching google for solutions, but I wasn't able to find anything

[Errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swRCt.png)

[Working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNBPd.png)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Employee Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#header").load("header.html");
    $("#content").load("startingContent.html");
    $("#footer").load("footer.html");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<header>
<nav id="menu">
    <img id="logo" src="Images/logo.png"  height="150" style="border: 5px solid black">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="ftp://wtpa.ddns.net/Site/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="ftp://wtpa.ddns.net/Site/calendar.html">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="ftp://wtpa.ddns.net/Site/contacts.html">Contacts</a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">File Server</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Documents</a>
                <a href="#">GameFiles</a>
                <a href="#">Videos</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</header>
```

style.css

```
.menu {
width: 100%;
vertical-align:top;
height:25px;
float: top;
 }

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
display:inline-block;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {

display: block;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hit F12 to check console, you'll see some error messages that will help you

Comment: Maybe you need MAMP or XAMP to run that code I'm not sure but if you use `.load()` you need to do a request that on just local doesn't work, that's why you need a virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it appears that your navigation is using absolute linking.

```
<li> <a href="ftp://wtpa.ddns.net/Site/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="ftp://wtpa.ddns.net/Site/calendar.html">Calendar</a>
</li>
<li> <a href="ftp://wtpa.ddns.net/Site/contacts.html">Contacts</a>
</li>
```

Furthermore, you can bring up you console, see what parts of your website refuse to load at all and change the routing.

**EDIT**

You cannot load these resources clearly for security reasons. Running pages through file:// protocol have disabled a lot of features because security issues. You can always create a javascript server using Node.js and host it locally without installing apache or something similar.

https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the images in the initial post. I have edited it and added the images of the site when its working and when it isn't with the errors

Comment: Just answered your question @K.Ward !

Answer (score 1):

Typical issue for local development is open content just like file in browser:

```
file:// ...
```

and then with some dynamic elements you can get error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:/// ... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Solution is install [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) on your local machine and open through http(s) protocol - eg. [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or use online service for that like [WebCloud](https://webcloud.io/).

See woking example on http [here](https://webcloud.io/bruno.onlyme@gmail.com/kward---employee-page/).

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the other files are in the same folder  with index.html. The problem probably is that it cant find locally the other files.
To be sure you can copy all the files in a directory(for example Desktop) and then try again.